# Infinite number of backup files with RollingFileAppender

Tags: java, logging, log4j, rollingfileappender

Do you know a way to create an infinite number of backup files with the [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html)?

When I don't specify any `maxBackupIndex` at all, I end up with only one backup file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible. See the [Log4J API](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html#setMaxBackupIndex(int)) :

> The MaxBackupIndex option determines how many backup files are kept before the oldest is erased. This option takes a positive integer value. If set to zero, then there will be no backup files and the log file will be truncated when it reaches MaxFileSize.

The best you can do is using a very large limit (Integer.MAX_VALUE will be the max).

Comment: Unfortunately, the RollingFileAppender freezes when I use Integer.MAX_VALUE. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `DailyRollingFileAppender`. That way your log only cycles once a day.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of infinite, how about `Integer.MAX_INT`?